# Any idea why my simple script stops working halfway down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple modal script that worked fine in the past, but for some reason it will refuse to work after the 10th image.

```
        <div class = "images_container"> <!-- Image 1 -->
            <div class = "images image_1">
                <div class = "hover_alpha">
                    <div class = "plus">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "images image_2"> <!-- Image 2 -->
                <div class = "hover_alpha">
                    <div class = "plus">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "images image_3"> <!-- Image 3 -->
                <div class = "hover_alpha">
                    <div class = "plus">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

```
<div id="image_1_content"> 
        <img src = "images/1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="image_2_content"> 
        <img src = "images/2.jpg">
</div>
<div id="image_3_content"> 
        <img src = "images/3.jpg">
```

```
        $('.image_1').click(function () {
            $('#image_1_content').modal({
                close: true,
                overlayClose:true,
                position: [150,70],
                opacity:80,
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
            });

            return false;
        });

        $('.image_2').click(function () {
            $('#image_2_content').modal({
                close: true,
                overlayClose:true,
                opacity:80,
                position: [150,70],
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
            });

            return false;
        });

        $('.image_3').click(function () {
            $('#image_3_content').modal({
                close: true,
                overlayClose:true,
                opacity:80,
                position: [150,70],
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
            });

            return false;
        });
```

The code is pretty much identical to the 21st image. However, the script refuses to work after the 9th image, starting from the 10th image. I'm baffled as to why or how this is happening. Any input?

Reference: http://spuxystudios.com/cocktails/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class selector, and iterate through them, or something of that matter to consolidate your code, and use less code. Also, lowers chance of a typo or syntax related bug.  Also, it is working, but is being placed out of the viewport. Just zoom out and you will see. It places based on how the element fell on the dom. So just fix how you are placing the modal. Thats all!

Comment: Very odd.. Any idea why that might be happening? As I said, the coding for the images are almost all identical -- I've double, triple checked and I have set the correct location of the window to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you referenced to you change `position: [150, 70]` to higher values, this and `position: fixed` makes your modal appear where it is not visible. Put `position: [150, 70]` everywhere. Also, you should follow @Casey advice and use iteration to reduce amount of code.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on now. I've originally entered the positions so that it'd work in a Facebook tab. Working fine as a FB tab: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Spuxy-Studios/161352630592219?id=161352630592219&sk=app_208195102528120

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the site, you can see that the position is actually different for each row of images. Here is an example:

```
        $('.image_6').click(function () {
            $('#image_6_content').modal({
                close: true,
                overlayClose:true,
                opacity:80,
                position: [550,30],
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
            });

            return false;
        });
        $('.image_7').click(function () {
            $('#image_7_content').modal({
                close: true,
                overlayClose:true,
                opacity:80,
                position: [950,30],
                overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
            });

            return false;
        });
```

As others have said, this is better done with a generic class.
You can put the content in the same div and hide it by default.

```
<div class="cocktails">
  <div class="cocktail">
    <img 1>
    <div class="more_info">modal content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cocktail">
    <img 2>
    <div class="more_info">modal content</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.cocktails').on('click', 'img', function() {
  $('.more_info', $(this)).modal({
    close: true,
    overlayClose:true,
    opacity:80,
    position: [150,70],
    overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"}                    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

like others have noticed, the positioning is not consistent. i dont see your CSS but maybe you can get a quick win with some nifty CSS setting. Try positioning the pop-up relative to the window